# minGW для qt на windows 64-bit(и не только)

Tags: c++, qt, mingw

Я сейчас второй раз устанавливаю qt.И так как в первый раз я не понял что minGW можно скачать с qt,я решил переустановить qt чтобы вместе с ним получить minGW.

И такой вопрос:в установщике (offline) есть только minGW 32bit.Он подходит на windows 64-bit а если нет,то что делать??

P.S что такое strawberry perl???

Comment: Подходит. 32 битные приложения будут работать и на 64 битной системе, но не наоборот -- если приложение 64 битное, то его на 32 битной системе не запустить

Comment: @gil9red то есть если у меня minGW 32bit я могу работать на нем?

Comment: Да, главное чтобы Qt тоже был совместим с minGW

Comment: а как это определить?(если minGW 32bit в установщике qt 64bit то совместимы?)

Comment: @1-originalname- Возьмите с официального сайт qt установщик онлайн, и установите. Потом попробуйте запустить hello world. Если запустился - значит всё хорошо. Если нет - возьмите с официального сайта qt установщик онлайн, ..... Там из чекбоксов надо выставить по минимуму - qtcreator, mingw и и ещё что-то с той же версией min gw. Щас подскажет кто-нибудь у кого под рукой. Ну и если Вы взяли установщик с оф сайта - то там всё совместимо. Они же выложили это, не дураки вроде

Comment: @1-originalname-, знаете я могу ошибаться, но при установке у вас будет возможность поддерживаемые версии mingw или Microsoft VC++ (visual studio 2015, visual studio 2017, и т.п.)

Comment: я верно понимаю что вы хотите статическую сборку делать?

Comment: strawberry perl - пакет для поддержки языка perl. Его обычно ставят когда хотят делать статическую линковку с библиотекой qt

Comment: @1-originalname- вот тут вся нужная вам информация https://habr.com/sandbox/95171/

Comment: @Alex.B спасибо

Comment: Можно поставить MSYS2 и в нём установить MinGW-w64 и QtCreator. Там доступны обе разрядности (32/64 bit), а также статическая линковка. https://wiki.qt.io/MSYS2