# системы сборки c++ в qt

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qmake, qbs

Переустановив qt (звучит как прям история,[minGW для qt на windows 64-bit(и не только)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/853030/mingw-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-qt-%D0%BD%D0%B0-windows-64-bit%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE)) и отогнав сомнения насчет minGW я захотел в qt creator написать hello world...

И тут задумался:что за системы сборок? Пользовался qmake(потому что по дефолту стояла).

Короче можете простыми словами объяснить что такое qmake,Cmake,Qbs...Пожалуйста

Comment: начать лучше наверное с qmake. А потом, разобравшись и попрактиковавшись, перейти на qbs или CMake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- qmake - система сборки, родная для Qt. Не знаете что использовать - берите ее. Нативно работает с QtCreator.
- Cmake - популярная система сборки. Умеет собирать разнообразные проекты под разнообразные оси/среды разработки. Умеет собирать и Qt проекты, но требует немного "телодвижений". QtCreator умеет с ней хорошо работать, но иногда как то оно странно (но может это мне везет).
- [qbs](http://doc.qt.io/qbs/overview.html) - попытка "исправить qmake", написать все заново и правильно. Также всякие новомодные штуки - json подобный стиль файла проекта, модули, сборки под разные оси.
- почитать холивора на [lor](https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/development/11307370)
- от самий разработчиков Qt [статистика](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_build_systems_at_QtCon_2016)